# Issue with Android SDK installation with titanium

Tags: android, installation, titanium

I'm trying to install android sdk with Appcelerator Titanium.

Android SDK seems fine but when I try to run the emulator, it says Android SDK is not installed.

Error log file says:

```
Logfile initialized
[INFO] logfile = /Users/ptamzz/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Jellow/build.log
[DEBUG] /Users/ptamzz/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/android/builder.py emulator Jellow /Applications/android-sdk-macosx /Users/ptamzz/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Jellow com.ptamzz.jellow 2 WVGA854
```

From the screenshot, it asks to install V10 of Platform SDK & Google API.

[image: Screenshot 1]

What are the options that I've to select from below while installing?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Your problem is self explanatory .First screenShot "You may install additional SDKs but you must install these (version 10 of sdk platform and google APIs)" versions.

Comment: I know. I tried installing what's mentioned there but it is *not* working. That's why I came here, thought I might have missed out something.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install minimum Required android Sdk [Android 2.3 => API LEVEL 10](http://postimg.org/image/dmu19ifu3/)

Comment: How do I check which titanium SDK am I using?

Comment: [tiSdk](http://postimg.org/image/3wl1wnnqf/)   [tiapp Overview](http://postimg.org/image/aygotvc0z/)